# How do Excel PivotTables determine their default sort order?

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I have a somewhat odd request in that I have some raw data that's being manipulated then transformed into a PivotTable in Excel 2013 with VBA. The catch is that the table should be sorted by it's first column, then second column, then third, and so on, BUT there shouldn't be a filter icon in the header row dropdown.

When the table is output, my first column values ("Year" values) are not in order as shown below. Does any one have an understanding of why this might be?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just created a data set with labels like above and a pivot table. The data sorts fine.

[image]

You may want to go through your data with a fine tooth comb and inspect the labels for periods 03 and 04 for rogue characters that might cause the wrong sort order.

Drag the cells into the correct sort order, refresh the pivot table and then create a new pivot table via your VBA. Report back if that does not solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the help teylyn.  I can manually put them in order by clicking the "Year" drop-down and sorting alphabetically which leads me to believe that it's not a data issue but rather the default sort mechanism. Does that make sense? Here's a screenshot of it sorting correctly when I manually do it: http://i.imgur.com/dXbfMxA.png

Comment: If you copy the raw data to a new file and create a new pivot table, does it sort correctly? If so, it's the pivot cache that's to blame. It may have become corrupt.

Comment: Thank you again Teylyn. I have manually put the data in and created a new pivot table and I am seeing the same results. I have given and and just decided to do the manual sort after the fact because I don't have any more time to devote to this. I'd like to submit your answer as the answer because it will probably help most people in a similar situation. Can you offer it as an answer? Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "can you offer it as an answer". The suggestion to do a manual sort is in my answer in the last paragraph. "Drag the cells into the correct sort order..." Do you want me to write something else?

Comment: Yep you're right, missed that on my phone. Thank you again!